# I printed the info from the database inside the h3 element. I want to read the info from here and send it to the data in export default?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
...
 <div v-for="q in question" :key="q" >
            <h3> {{q.content}} </h3>
            <h3> A) {{q.a}}  </h3>
            <h3> B) {{q.b}} </h3> 
            <h3> C) {{q.c}} </h3>
            <h3> D) {{q.d}} </h3>
           <v-btn v-if="veritabani" class="mt-2 primary"  @click="add" > Add </v-btn>
        </div>
...
export default{
data()
{ 
item:''
}
...
```

I want to send the information from the first h3 into the item. How do I do it in Vue.js?

Comment: can you create an online example, I think it can make your question clearly
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in questions" :key="index">
    <h3> {{item.content}} </h3>
    <h3> A) {{item.a}} </h3>
    <h3> B) {{item.b}} </h3>
    <h3> C) {{item.c}} </h3>
    <h3> D) {{item.d}} </h3>
    
    <button @click="setItem(item)">
      Add
    </button>
   
    
  <!--   <v-btn v-if="veritabani" class="mt-2 primary" @click="add"> Add </v-btn> -->
  </div>
  
  <div>
    Selected Item: {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    "questions": [
        {
        "content": "My first question",
        "a": "Option A",
        "b": "Option B",
        "c": "Option C",
        "d": "Option D"
      }
    ],
    item: null
  },
  methods: {
    setItem (item) {
        this.item = item
    }
  }
})
```

[JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/)

[image: Preview]